Random variable with the same distribution as its square
I ask myself the following question. Can a random variable $ X $ have the same distribution as its square? If this happens, what about the distribution function of $ X $?
Thank you.

Your question is equivalent to finding a function $f$ such that $f(x) = (f(x))^2$ and $f(x)$ is integrable, I think (the integrable condition comes from the fact that your variable should have a well defined cumulative density function alongside a PDF)

Yes, a random variable $X$ can have the same distribution as its square.
For example, let $X \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p), p \in [0, 1]$. Then $X^2 \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$. Indeed, we have the following:
$$
    \mathbb{P}(X^2 = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X = 0) = 1 - p, \text{ and } \mathbb{P}(X^2 = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X = 1) = p
$$

This adds to above answer by proving that if $X$ and $X^{2}$ have the same distribution then  $X$ can take only the values $0$ and $1$:
By iteration $X$ and $X^{2^{n}}$ have the same distribution. This shows that $E|X|1_{|X|<1}=E|X|^{2^{n}}1_{|X|<1}$ (becasue $|X|<1$ iff $|X|^{2^{n}}<1$).
Applying DCT we see that $E|X|1_{|X|<1}=0$. This implies that $X=0$ a.s  on $\{|X|<1\}$.
Similarly, $X$ and $X^{2^{-n}}$ have the same distribution. Integrating over $(|X|> 1)$ we see as before that $P(|X|>1)=0$.
Thus $X$ can take only the values $0,+1$ and $-1$. But $P(X=1)=P(X^{2}=1)=P(X=1)+P(X=-1)$ proving that $P(X=-1)=0$.
